# Updating 1000 records at once

Tags: php, updates

Let's say I have a list with 1000 user id's, and I want to update their payment status, I payed them and now I want to update their status as completed.

If I do it with a loop it can create 1000 updates which will be very demanding on the database. Is there a better way?

I see 2 options right now, one with a loop, and another one is to build the query string dynamically like:

```
$query = UPDATE users SET somecolumn WHERE user_id = '$user_id1' AND    user_id = 'user_id2 AND... etc...
```

Comment: You can actually write 'WHERE user_id IN (...)' and then just keep adding the ids inside the parenthesis - it will save you some trouble building the query.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a query using IN:

$query = "UPDATE users SET somecolumn='value' WHERE user_id IN ('$user_id1', '$user_id2')";

Comment: This is the way I would probably do it. +1

Comment: thank you very much, it looks good, and then i need to put 1000 user id's right? inside the brackets

Comment: Yes, add as many user ids as required in the brackets. If this has solved your question please select the answer.

Comment: As usual with PHP - or any other language  you'll want to use prepared statements for additional security (treating data as data, and not as a direct part of the SQL). This just means as many placeholders as you have data, and then pass in an array of the user_id's.